# Passing data from custom table cell to text fields

Tags: ios

I am creating a demo app of an Address Book, which saves people info in an array and displays it in a custom table cell.

The first controller saves the info entered by the user in text fields in an array.
The second controller displays the info in a custom table cell.
The third controller is the same as the first with the only difference is that it will be used not for storing data, but to update the data.
What I now want is to update the table cell data. I have created an update button, on click I am segueing to the 3rd controller.

What I want is the information displayed in a particular cell, to be passed to the 3rd view controller text fields, when the update button is clicked.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you store your data in some array or something similar structure. So you can get data from it like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    MyThirdViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThirdViewController"];
    vc.dataToDisplay = self.myDataArray[indexPath.row];
}
```

Then in your third view controller you will have data you need to display.
For example if you know order of data in your new array, you can fill your text fields like this

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //if your data is an array
    self.firstTextField.text = self.dataToDisplay[0];
    self.secondTextField.text = self.dataToDisplay[1];
    //and so on
    //if your data is a dictionary
    self.firstTextField.text = self.dataToDisplay[@"name"];  //for string objects
    self.secondTextField.text = [self.dataToDisplay[@"age"] integerValue];  //for integer values
}
```

Comment: I have done it like this, created another array to hold the info, but how can I get the object from this array to display in the text field?

Comment: I am getting an error "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e18ff0"

Also if the array consists of one object with multiple date e.g name, age, number.

If one object in an array contains this much info, how can it be stored in their respective text fields

Comment: Okay. Lets start it again. First of all your data should be as an array of dictionaries. Then when you select some cell you will get a dictionary from your array and send in to your third view controller. After that just fill your text fields with objects from dictionary. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
//in your third viewcontroller.h
@property NSString * textfieldname;
@property NSString * textfieldage;

//in your second viewcontroller.m

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"identifiername"]){

NSIndexPath *ip = [yourtablename indexPathForSelectedRow];
thirdviewcontrollerr *targetVC = [segue destinationViewController];

    targetVC.textfieldname=[[arrayname objectatindex:ip.row]valueforkey:name];
    targetVC.textfieldage=[[arrayname objectatindex:ip.row]valueforkey:age];
//in your thirdviewcontroller.m
 nametextfield.text=_textfieldname;
 agetextfield.text=_textfieldage;
```

Comment: I am getting an error "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e18ff0"

Also if the array consists of one object with multiple date e.g name, age, number.

If one object in an array contains this much info, how can it be stored in their respective text fields